# fs.rename callback function not executing in nodejs filesystem

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I am trying to rename the directories if it contains space in their name.
It's renaming properly but after renaming call back function defined never called.

my recursive function in below, where fs for **file system** and **complete-directory-tree**.

```
function renameDir(dirs){
    dirs.forEach(function(e){

        if(e.name.match(/\s+/g)){
            var cname = e.name.replace(/\s+/g,'_');
            var cpath = e.path.replace(e.name,cname);
            fs.rename(e.path,cpath,function(err,data){
                if(err) console.log(err)
                else{
                    console.log('success');
                    e.path = cpath;
                    e.name = cname;   
                }
            });
        }

        var nested = cDT(e.path)
        if( nested.children && (nested.children.length > 0) ) renameDir(nested.children);
    });
}
```

Comment: It runs asynchronously, so any code you have which looks at the values in `dirs` after you call `renameDir` will run *before* the callbacks have run.

Comment: @Quentin, yeah i tried only `console.log('success')`, even. But It looks like it never logged. Still all the directories renamed perfectly.

Comment: @Quentin please try at your end and let me know. And please mind EVEN I TRIED WITH CONSOLE.LOG ALONE , BUT IT'S NOT LOGGING IT IN CONSOLE, BUT THE OPERATION / RENAMING PROCESS SUCCESSFUL. And I am using `fs.rename` not `fs.renameSync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code and path should be depend on your folder structure

```
'use strict';
const [fs, path] = [require('fs'), require('path')];

fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, data) => {
data.map(d => {
    if (d.includes(' ')) {
        let name = d.replace(/ /g, '_');
        fs.renameSync(path.resolve(__dirname, d), path.resolve(__dirname, name));
    }
})});
```